# Java Socket Server Application : Getting the packet after long delay

Tags: java, linux, sockets, port, smpp

I have a socket server (an Java SMPP server) to which huge number of clients connect and submit requests.
The issue occurs when there are huge number concurrent packets sent to the socket server, although the machine receives the request (captured from tcpdump) at 'X' time , the request reaches the application 
after x + n (seconds). Setting the backlog to an higher value didnt help too.

Not sure where am I going wrong. Can there be a situation where the machine receives the request on a port but the socket server running on that port receiving it after long delay? If so, what tuning needs to be done on the application (java) end,  LINUX machine end

Appreciate any help.

```
private void listen()
{
    try {
        Connection connection = null;
        serverConn.setReceiveTimeout(getAcceptTimeout());
        connection = serverConn.accept();


        if (connection != null) {
            --start the session thread (run method below--
                    Thread thread = new Thread(session);
            thread.start();
        } else {
            debug.write(Simulator.DSIMD2, "no connection accepted this time.");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
        debug.write("InterruptedIOException accepting, timeout? -> " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        keepReceiving = false;
    }
}

public Connection accept()
throws IOException
{
    IOException exception = null;

    Connection newConn = null;
    if (connType == CONN_SERVER) {
        try {
            receiverSocket.setSoTimeout((int)getReceiveTimeout());
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // don't care, we're just setting the timeout
        }
        Socket acceptedSocket = null;
        try {
            acceptedSocket = receiverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        if (acceptedSocket != null) {
            try {
                newConn = new TCPIPConnection(acceptedSocket);
                address = acceptedSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Acceptedsocket  Address " + address);
                    System.out.println("ReceiverSocket Address " + receiverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((TCPIPConnection)newConn).setAddress(address);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                debug.write("IOException creating new client connection "+e);
                event.write(e,"IOException creating new client connection");
                exception = e;
            }
        }
    } else if (connType == CONN_CLIENT) {
        debug.write("Attempt to receive data from client type connection.");
    } else {
        debug.write("Unknown connection type = " + connType);
    }

    debug.exit(DCOMD,this);
    if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
    }
    return newConn;
}

    public void run() 
{
    PDU pdu = null;
    while (keepReceiving)
    {

        pdu = receiver.receive(getReceiveTimeout());

        if (pdu != null) {
            --- DO SOME PROCESSING ----
        }
        }
 }

public ByteBuffer receive()
throws IOException
{
    debug.enter(DCOMD,this,"receive");
    IOException exception = null;

    ByteBuffer data = null;
    if (connType == CONN_CLIENT) {
        data = new ByteBuffer();
        long endTime = Data.getCurrentTime() + getReceiveTimeout();
        //int bytesAvailable = 0;
        int bytesToRead = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout((int)getCommsTimeout());
            bytesToRead = receiveBufferSize;
            debug.write(DCOMD,"going to read from socket");
            debug.write(DCOMD,"comms timeout="+getCommsTimeout()+
                        " receive timeout="+getReceiveTimeout()+
                        " receive buffer size="+receiveBufferSize);
            do {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try {
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
                    // comms read timeout expired, no problem
                    debug.write(DCOMD,"timeout reading from socket");
                }
                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    debug.write(DCOMD,"read "+bytesRead+" bytes from socket");
                    data.appendBytes(receiveBuffer,bytesRead);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                bytesToRead = inputStream.available();
                if (bytesToRead>0) {
                    debug.write(DCOMD,"more data ("+bytesToRead+" bytes) remains in the socket");
                } else {
                    debug.write(DCOMD,"no more data remains in the socket");
                }
                if (bytesToRead > receiveBufferSize) {
                    bytesToRead = receiveBufferSize;
                }
                if (totalBytesRead+bytesToRead > maxReceiveSize) {
                    // would be more than allowed
                    bytesToRead = maxReceiveSize - totalBytesRead;
                }
            } while (((bytesToRead!=0) && (Data.getCurrentTime()<=endTime))
                     && (totalBytesRead < maxReceiveSize));

            debug.write(DCOM,"totally read "+data.length()+" bytes from socket");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.write("IOException " + e);
            event.write(e,"IOException receive via TCPIPConnection");
            exception = e;
        }
    } else if (connType == CONN_SERVER) {
        debug.write("Attempt to receive data from server type connection.");
    } else {
        debug.write("Unknown connection type = " + connType);
    }

    debug.exit(DCOMD,this);
    if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Thanks and Regards
Raaghu.K

Comment: How are you pulling requests off of the socket? How are you handling concurrent requests within your application? Have you exceeded your application's concurrency causing requests to queue?

Comment: There is a dedicated thread after every 'bind' client request. The client requests from there on will be handled in that thread.(basically reading from stream). Is it possible to check application's concurrency limit?

Comment: Are you allocating threads from a pool (such as using a ThreadPoolExecutor), or are you newing Threads directly? Can you provide code examples of how you are pulling connections from server socket and allocating the work?

Comment: No we are not using any pool / executors. Instead we start a new thread

Comment: Are you doing any I/O in the accepting thread? That includes unsuspecting I/O done when constructing session and session-handling objects.

Comment: I have just pasted the code the first method is the continuous thread to receive message., which calls the second method
Second method shows how we receive the data from stream

Comment: Paste the code for the accepting thread and any methods or constructors it calls. NB You could save a lot of data copying by advancing the offset pointer in the read call instead.

Comment: Constructing a new thread is an expensive operation, and Java is not designed for real time computing. Under heavy load, delays may occurs almost anywhere between to consecutive instructions. I do not think that the packet has been stolen, but the time to create a thread, and have it to begin the treatement of the packet may easily be greater than 1 second - under heavy load, but you say you are receiving a huge number of packets and so create a huge number or threads. IMHO using thread pooling should improve performances.

Comment: @EJP I might be your getting the question wrong, first run() is the thread which accepts the packets. 
Also, can you please suggest where to change the offset

Comment: Blimey. Please post *the loop that accepts connections* and the code for any methods or constructors that it calls. The method that accepts connections is called Socket.accept(). The method that *reads data* is called read(). And I have *already told you* where to change the offset. In the read() method. Is this really so difficult?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I might not be very clear We are not creating thread for each packet. Thread will be created when the connection is made for the first time (bind request) post that clients will be submitting requests and the same will be handled in the thread which is already created

Comment: The thread should be created when you accept the connection, not on any request. This is your problem.

Comment: @EJP . I have pasted the code which first accept the connection and a starts a session thread.

Comment: Move the setting of the connection IP address into the TCPIPConnection class. Better still, get rid of it. You don't need it. It's there in the Socket any time you need it. At present you are doing a DNS lookup in the accepting thread. This is exactly the sort of thing I warned about above. And you don't need to keep setting the accept timeout on every accept. And you still haven't posted the *loop* that calls accept. Third time of asking. The loop shouldn't do anything except accept connections and create threads. And why do you have two methods that call accept()?

Comment: @EJP. Ok I will remove the line which sets the connection IP. This would have caused the delay?
Actually the code which calls listen() method is called like this
`code`
while (keepReceiving) {
                listen();
            }
In the listen() we do not do anything other than accept(). So this is fine I think

Answer (score 0):

There is far too much going on in your accept() code even without seeing the loop(s) that call it. An accept loo should look like this:

```
while (true)    // or other condition
{
    new Thread(new TCPIPConnection(ServerSocket.accept())).start();
}
```

error-handling etc omitted. The longer you spend doing other things in this loop the more you will delay subsequent clients.

Your code by contrast does a potentially expensive and delaying DNS lookup per client, which is in fact wholly redundant, as the address is available to the client via the Socket any time it is required.

There is also too much logging, or at least logging in the wrong place, and the code is very poorly structured, with catch blocks in the wrong place, often empty, and followed by code that should be inside the try block. Fixing that will also eliminate the need for all those null tests.

As another example, you don't need to keep resetting the accept timeout every time you call accept. The presence of two accept() calls in different methods also indicates either a bug or a relic of a previous iteration of the code.

There also seems to be some attempt to share client and server code at this level, which is nonsense. Clients don't accept connections, and they usually start by sending requests, not receiving them. Or, if they start with a receive, the server must start with a send. You can't share this stuff. You can share the actual I/O code, e.g. quasi-serialization code, but not send/receive logic, and certainly not connection-accepting code.

Your post and comments also exhibit a lot of confusion. Connections are accepted: data is read. Data is not accepted. The same kind of confusion is there in the code as well. Clear thinking leads to clear code.

You need to pay attention to all of this, and also to what happens in the constructor for TCPIPConnection. Eliminate any time-intensive or potentially blocking operation,particularly network I/O: move it to the beginning of the run() method.